# What's wrong with this SELECT Statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, foreign-keys, create-table

I'm getting this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '' JOIN `shirts_link` ON `shirts_link`.`shirt_id`=`shirts`.`id`
>   JOIN `shirt_sizes' at line 1

I've been combing over it for nearly a half an hour now and can't figure it out.  Can someone please point it out to me?  Here's the code.

```
SELECT
`shirts`.`shirt_name`,
`shirts`.`men` AS `main_photo`,
GROUP_CONCAT ( `shirt_sizes`.`size_name` ) AS `sizes`
FROM
`shirts`
JOIN
`shirts_link` ON `shirts_link`.`shirt_id`=`shirts`.`id`
JOIN
`shirt_sizes` ON `shirt_sizes`.`id`=`shirts_link`.`size_id`
JOIN
`shirt_prices` ON `shirt_prices`.`id`=`shirts_link`.`price_id`
WHERE `men`!=''
GROUP BY
`shirt_prices`.`price_cat`
```

In case the problem goes deeper than this script, here's the other tables I'm trying to tie together.

Shirts Table

```
CREATE TABLE shirts (
    id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    shirt_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    men VARCHAR(10) NULL,
    women VARCHAR(10) NULL,
    boys VARCHAR(10) NULL,
    girls VARCHAR(10) NULL,
    babies VARCHAR(10) NULL,
)ENGINE=INNODB;

INSERT INTO shirts(shirt_name,men,women,boys,girls,babies) VALUES
    ('Crewneck Tee','me_crn','wo_crn','bo_crn','gi_crn','ba_crn'),
    ('V-Neck Tee','me_vnc','wo_vnc','','',''),
    ('Scoop Neck Tee','','wo_sco','','',''),
    ('Raglan Tee','me_rag','wo_rag','bo_rag','gi_rag',''),
    ('Ringer Tee','me_rin','wo_rin','bo_rin','gi_rin',''),
    ('Cap Sleeve Tee','','wo_cap','','gi_cap',''),
    ('Tank Top','me_tan','wo_tan','bo_tan','gi_tan',''),
    ('Spaghetti Strap','','wo_spa','','',''),
    ('Hoodie','me_hod','wo_hod','bo_hod','gi_hod','ba_hod'),
    ('Onsie','','','','','ba_ons');
```

Size Table

```
CREATE TABLE shirt_sizes (
    id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    size_name VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
)ENGINE=INNODB;


INSERT INTO shirt_sizes(size_name) VALUES
    ('new born'),
    ('6 months'),
    ('12 months'),
    ('18 months'),
    ('2T'),
    ('3T'),
    ('4T'),
    ('5T'),
    ('x-small'),
    ('small'),
    ('medium'),
    ('large'),
    ('1x-large'),
    ('2x-large'),
    ('3x-large'),
    ('4x-large'),
    ('5x-large');
```

Price Table

```
CREATE TABLE shirt_prices (
    id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    price_cat VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    price NUMERIC(6,2) NOT NULL
    )ENGINE=INNODB;

INSERT INTO shirt_prices(price_cat,price) VALUES
    ('crn_01','25.40'),('crn_02','26.30'),('crn_03','27.20'),('crn_04','28.10'),   
        ('crn_05','29.11'),

        ('vnc_01','26.21'),('vnc_02','27.11'),('vnc_03','28.01'),('vnc_04','29.02'),  
        ('vnc_05','30.80'),

        ('sco_01','28.10'),

        ('rag_01','29.22'),('rag_02','30.44'),('rag_03','31.70'),('rin_01','29.22'),
        ('rin_02','30.44'),('rin_03','31.70'),

        ('cap_01','29.04'),('cap_02','30.26'),

        ('tan_01','25.31'),('tan_02','26.21'),

        ('spa_01','26.30'),('spa_02','27.11'),

        ('hod_01','35.21'),('hod_02','36.11'),('hod_03','37.10'),('hod_04','38.11');
```

Shirt Link Table

```
CREATE TABLE shirts_link (
        adult VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
        kids VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
        babies VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
        shirt_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
        size_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
        price_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (shirt_id,size_id,price_id),
        FOREIGN KEY (`shirt_id`) REFERENCES `shirts`(`id`),
        FOREIGN KEY (`size_id`) REFERENCES shirt_sizes(`id`),
        FOREIGN KEY (`price_id`) REFERENCES shirt_prices(`id`)
    )ENGINE=INNODB;

    INSERT INTO shirts_link (adult, kids, babies, shirt_id, size_id, price_id) VALUES
    ('n','n','y','1','1','1'),('n','n','y','1','2','1'),('n','n','y','1','3','1'),('n','n','y','1','4','1'),
    ('n','n','y','1','5','1'),('n','n','y','1','6','1'),('n','n','y','1','7','1'),('n','n','y','1','8','1'),
    ('n','y','n','1','9','1'),('y','y','n','1','10','1'),('y','y','n','1','11','1'),('y','y','n','1','12','1'),
    ('y','y','n','1','13','1'),('y','n','n','1','14','2'),('y','n','n','1','15','3'),('y','n','n','1','16','4'),
    ('y','n','n','1','17','5'),

    ('y','n','n','2','10','6'),('y','n','n','2','11','6'),('y','n','n','2','12','6'),('y','n','n','2','13','6'),
    ('y','n','n','2','14','7'),('y','n','n','2','15','8'),('y','n','n','2','16','9'),('y','n','n','2','17','10'),

    ('y','n','n','3','10','11'),('y','n','n','3','11','11'),('y','n','n','3','12','11'),('y','n','n','3','13','11'),
    ('y','n','n','3','14','11'),

    ('y','y','n','4','10','12'),('y','y','n','4','11','12'),('y','y','n','4','12','12'),('y','y','n','4','13','12'),
    ('y','n','n','4','14','13'),('y','n','n','4','15','14'),

    ('y','y','n','5','10','15'),('y','y','n','5','11','15'),('y','y','n','5','12','15'),('y','y','n','5','13','15'),
    ('y','n','n','5','14','16'),('y','n','y','5','15','17'),

    ('y','y','n','6','10','18'),('y','y','n','6','11','18'),('y','y','n','6','12','18'),('y','y','n','6','13','18'),
    ('y','n','n','6','14','19'),

    ('y','y','n','7','10','20'),('y','y','n','7','11','20'),('y','y','n','7','12','20'),('y','y','n','7','13','20'),
    ('y','n','n','7','14','21'),

    ('y','n','n','8','10','22'),('y','n','n','8','11','22'),('y','n','n','8','12','22'),('y','n','n','8','13','22'),
    ('y','n','n','8','14','23'),

    ('n','n','y','9','5','24'),('n','n','y','9','6','24'),('n','n','y','9','7','24'),('n','n','y','9','8','24'),
    ('n','n','y','9','9','24'),('y','y','n','9','10','24'),('y','y','n','9','11','24'),('y','y','n','9','12','24'),
    ('y','y','n','9','13','24'),('y','y','n','9','14','25'),('y','n','n','9','15','26'),('y','n','n','9','16','27'),
    ('y','n','n','9','16','25'),

    ('n','n','y','10','1','1'),('n','n','y','10','2','1'),('n','n','y','10','3','1'),('n','n','y','10','4','1');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have this `WHERE` clause in the wrong place:

```
WHERE `men`!=''
```

Move it in front of your `GROUP BY` clause.

**UPDATE:**   Here is a reformatted version of your query:

```
SELECT   `shirts`.`shirt_name`
       , `shirts`.`men` AS `main_photo`
       , GROUP_CONCAT ( `shirt_sizes`.`size_name` ) AS `sizes`
FROM   `shirts`
JOIN   `shirts_link` 
ON     `shirts_link`.`shirt_id`=`shirts`.`id`
JOIN   `shirt_sizes` 
ON     `shirt_sizes`.`id`=`shirts_link`.`size_id`
JOIN   `shirt_prices`
ON     `shirt_prices`.`id`=`shirts_link`.`price_id'

WHERE  `men` != ''

GROUP BY `shirt_prices`.`price_cat`
```

Comment: So the WHERE clause should go last?.. or right on top of  the GROUP BY clause?

Comment: hmmm. I'm still getting an error either way. is the syntax for it correct?

Comment: Yes, after the last `JOIN` and before the `GROUP BY` clauses.

Comment: ok now I'm getting an error saying the group concat doesn't exist, smh, thanks for your help, at least the first problem is solved.

Answer (score 5):

Where clause belongs after the entire from clause, meaning after all the joins.

Comment: is the syntax of it correct? I'm still getting an error.  I even tried putting the table name in front of it but it didn't make a difference.